# Vick Exercise 2.6, can't spot my mistake

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In Vick's *Homology Theory*, Exercise 6 (pg. 49) refers to the following picture:

[image]

Let $X$ be the space given by the unit interval together with a family of segments approaching it. If $A$ is the unit interval, show that $A$ is a deformation retract of $X$ but not a strong deformation retract.

I am confused because isn't $H:X \times I \to X$ defined by
$$H((x,y),t) = \begin{cases}
(x,y) & (x,y) \in A \\
(1-t)(x,y) & (x,y) \in (X \backslash A) \cup \{(0,0)\}
\end{cases}$$ a strong deformation retract? $H$ essentially fixes $A$ while contracting all of the other segments to the origin. It is also continuous by the Pasting Lemma.

Where did I go wrong?

(A strong deformation retract is a continuous $F:X \times I \to X$ such that i) $F(x,0) = x \;\forall x \in X$, ii) $F(x,1) \in A \;\forall x \in X$, and iii) $F(a,t) = a \;\forall a \in A, t \in I$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $H$ is not continuous.

Note that when $(x_1,y_1)$ belongs to a segment which is very very close to $A$ and if $(x_2,y_2)$ is a point on $A$ very close to $(x_1,y_1)$, the points $H((x_1,y_1),1)=(0,0)$ and $H((x_2,y_2), 1)=(x_2,y_2)$ will typically not be close to each other.

Comment: I had a hunch this was the issue. But in this case, why doesn't the Pasting Lemma apply? $H$ is continuous on $A \times I$ and $[(X \backslash A) \cup \{(0,0)\}] \times I$, these are both closed subsets of $X \times I$, and the two functions agree on their intersection.

Comment: @JLinsta The fact that the segments converge to $A$ tell you that $A$ is in the closure of $X \backslash A$... Pasting Lemma requires the two sets to be closed.

Comment: @JLinsta The argument in my answer becomes much more clear if you try to figure what is the image under $H( \cdot, 1)$ of a ball of small radius at $(1,0)$. You'll see immediatelly the issue.

Comment: OH I see the issue here. I assumed there were only finitely many segments (like in the picture), so they do not get arbitrarily close to $A$. But $X$ actually contains infinitely many segments that get arbitrarily close to $A$.

Comment: @JLinsta Your argument is true if there are finitely many,:)

Comment: Yes this was driving me crazy. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Heuristically, points near A on a diagonal line will not stay near A when your retract is applied to them.